# Unity Admob v6.1.0 - "You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword" Warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, admob

this is the warning when I run the game

[image]

> You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.
> This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using
> AddComponent(). Alternatively, your script can inherit from
> ScriptableObject or no base class at all
> UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:.ctor () ButtonBehaviour:.ctor ()
> GoogleMobileAds.Unity.InterstitialClient:CreateButtonBehavior ()
> GoogleMobileAds.Unity.InterstitialClient:Show ()
> GoogleMobileAds.Api.InterstitialAd:Show ()
> AdManager:ShowInterstitialAd () (at Assets/Scripts/AdManager.cs:114)
> GameManager:GameOver () (at Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs:174)
> GameManager:UpdateLives (int) (at Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs:148)
> Target:ReverseHeartAnimation () (at Assets/Scripts/Target.cs:99)
> Target:OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider) (at
> Assets/Scripts/Target.cs:66)

My problem is very similar with this: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1804626/google-admob-reklamlar%C4%B1n%C4%B1-kullanam%C4%B1yorum.html

I am able to run my game and see test ads in computer but when I upload my bundle to play store it crashes and doesn't even open. Since I don't get any errors I suspect from ads. Somebody in groups said that:

> ```
> "The problem at the line buttonBehaviour = new ButtonBehaviour(); 
> in CreateButtonBehavior function
> in Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Platforms\Unity\BannerClient.cs
>
> I  replaced line buttonBehaviour = new ButtonBehaviour(); 
> with lines:
>            GameObject ob=new GameObject();
>             ob.AddComponent<ButtonBehaviour>();
>             buttonBehaviour = ob.GetComponent<ButtonBehaviour>();
>
> And warning gone."
> ```

However, I don't have "\Platforms\Unity\BannerClient.cs" and I don't have BannerClient.cs in anywhere. I think it's due to my GoogleMobileAds version.

[image]

I wanted to downgrade my GoogleMobileAds version but I thought deleting current files may cause more problem. That's why I wrote here first.

Does anyone know the solution of the problem? Experienced earlier?

Comment: That's just a warning, I always get it too, it doesn't hurt, my ads show up correctly and it's okay. To downgrade just delete all GMA folders and replace them with another plugin. But I really don't think the block is from ads. Use the Android Logcat to receive crash errors (find it in the Package Manager (https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.android-logcat@1.2/manual/index.html)), then show us the error.

Comment: Also check the insertion of the App ID, from version 6.0.0 it disappears when you close Unity, and must be entered every time or must be entered, then the Delay App Measurement must be activated and disabled. Enabling and disabling it triggers a save process. it's a known bug for months and months but they haven't fixed it yet

Comment: @FreeLearning did you upload yor game to play store with that warning? Yes it's just a warning but my game is very basic game and there is no other error or warning. Just that.  And the weird thing is it works fine in computer but when I upload it to store it doesnt even open. I tried to see logs like in here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1368808/how-to-see-debuglog-when-using-android.html
 But when I try to open game it wont open and there no error message :(
Btw. I insterted my App ID it doesn't disappear. Idk anything about Delay App Measurement. I will check it or I downgrade GMA

Comment: Of course I uploaded apps to the store with this warning, and they work. I think you didn't understand how to use the Logcat, you have to install the application from Unity on an Android device, then open the Logcat and lines will begin to appear telling what the device is running, at that point you click on the app icon you have installed and if it crashes you see the error.

Comment: @FreeLearning P.S. I solved the issue by downgrading GMA. I imported admob v5.3 thanks for your comments. I appreciate it.